# Alfresco aspect secondaryType

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

I have a probleme with openCmis with Alfresco in Java.
I try to add a secondaryType "abc:aspectCustom" to my document like we can see in this code :

```
props.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.value());
    props.put(PropertyIds.SECONDARY_OBJECT_TYPE_IDS, Arrays.asList("P:abc:aspectCustom"));
    ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(documentName, sizeFolder, typeFile, inputStream);
    Document document = targetFolder.createDocument(props, contentStream, VersioningState.CHECKEDOUT);
```

but i have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Secondary types property contains a type that is not a secondary type: P:abc:aspectCustom
```

So i tried to debug and i see that my problem come from this part of code (ObjectFactoryImpl) :

```
if (!(secondaryType instanceof SecondaryType)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Secondary types property contains a type that is not a secondary type: " + secondaryTypeId);
                }
```

and when i debug the **secondaryType** object i see that he's **instance of PolicyType** and not **SecondaryType**. 
So i dont now where is the probleme ! why my aspect in the model is interpreted as a Policy and not as a SecondaryType.

For information, in the model Alfresco i  have this :

```
<aspect name="abc:aspectCustom">
            <title>ABCAspect</title>
</aspect>
```

Thnakk you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using the CMIS 1.1 service URL, which is https://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom for the ATOMPub binding and https://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser for the Browser binding.

Next, try adding an out-of-the-box aspect, like P:cm:geographic, instead of your custom aspect, just to make sure that works. This will rule out any problems with your custom content model.

Comment: Hello Jeff, Thank you for the answer. It work's now :)

Comment: Was the problem that you were using the wrong CMIS service URL?

Comment: Yes, i used the right dependency in my pom, but the bad url :/